# How to do this div in HTML

Tags: css, html

There is a part of big layout - div which consists of 3 div's, so how to put them under each other when you zoom out the page? Tnx for watching!

[image]

Comment: Try a responsive css framework like bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic approach using floats and media queries: http://jsfiddle.net/8x5xchps/.  (Resize the screen to see the changes in the stacking order).

HTML:

```
<div id = "wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<p>Sample paragraph</p>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

#wrapper > div {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
}

#wrapper > div:first-of-type {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#wrapper > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

#wrapper > div:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #wrapper > div {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx, but what is > means and div:first-of-type,.etc?

Comment: The `>` is a child selector, so `#wrapper > div` will select all divs that are directly within the `#wrapper`.  The `:first-of-type` is a pseudo-class - it selects an element base on its state.  The selector `#wrapper > div:first-of-type` finds the very first `div` child within the `#wrapper`.  You are welcome to check out my "Functional CSS" books on amazon.  In these I explain most of CSS using only practical examples.  Cheers.